# can we inspect value in the cache after a read instruction has executed?

Tags: linux, caching, matrix, cpu

Recently, I write a program to transpose a matrix.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
     {
          for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
          {
               ndata[j][i] = odata[i][j];
          }
     }
```

From above code, we know inner loop is cache friendly for `odata`, however not friendly for `ndata`, which will lead a lot of `cache miss`, I want to inspect value of the L1 `cache` and L2 `cache` after a `read instruction` has executed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - 1000*1000*2 elements (of what, int?) won't fit in any L1 I know of, maybe an L3.

As for your question - there's no simple way to inspect the contents of a cache (expect for running it on a CPU or cache simulator that produces that information), you may measure the access time of that line but by that you would a) affect the contents of the cache or their LRU weights, and b) probably get meaningless results unless you measure accessing multiple such lines in a single measurement and amortize.

By the way, if you're interested in improving this code, just add SW prefetches for `ndata[j+1][i]` on each iteration.

Comment: the 1000 * 1000 * 2 elements are all int value. Now I intend to use simplescalar to help us understand the cache behaviour, and thank you for your advice.

Comment: @stonestrong, Ok then, simulating on simplescalar would work, just keep in mind that if you intend one day to parallelize it, it's not supported there, you can use gem5 or other move advanced simulators